# Add xml files to system.img while making a build

Tags: android

I have a requirement where I need to push a bunch of xml files into the system.img while making a build. 
So I want to know where should I place the xml files in source and how to write the Android.mk to get these xml files picked up while building.

Highly appreciate your help.

Comment: where in system.img do they need to go? What parts of the system need access to them? No one can answer this until you are a lot more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire approach on inserting a xml into a "build" is incorrect. What you **SHOULD** be doing is that you should put the XML files in the file system, and then refer to them from there. Basically in the init.rc file you would make the directory with your XML files in it.

This of course requires that you modify the make file of the build. Where you would map a file in the particular build to a specific place in the file system. Which of course would be referring to your actual platform build make file.